# How to keep reading from one socket in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a server that is always sending messages (from a Java socket) to any sockets connected. It also takes messages and preforms them. The latter works fine, but reading the constant stream of messages and giving them to the user is near-impossible. I can't do any HTML interaction without losing the socket resource, and I can't lose the connection to the server because I'll lose the messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Relay the socket information either via long-polling over AJAX (which would probably involve a queue) or websockets.

Comment: Use Websocket. While browser support isnt universal, it is the closest you will get to your goal. At least in the sense of http requests. You could simulate it by saving messages to another data store and having an ajax request read the new messages from the database.

Comment: @datasage I think that saving it to a database will work great! I'll let you know later if it works.